# htaccess - can't load files directly any more

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I goit this htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?p=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

So I can rewrite `example.com/123/hey` to `example.com/?p=123&title=hey`

But now I can't call files like `example.com/pics/jo.jpg` directly any more

Is there any way to call the files directly and keep the rewrite rules by modifying the htaccess or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you can't call your `/pics/jo.jpg` is because your your pattern `^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$` matches all requests of this form `/foo/bar` , so when `/foo/bar.jpg` is requested your rule rewrites it to `/?p=foo&title=bar.jpg` . To solve this ,you need to exclude your existent files and dirs from the rule using  RewriteConds

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?p=$1&title=$2 [L]
```